# LibreOffice Base - Hyperlink Macro

Tags: database, vbscript, scripting, macros, mozilla

### How would one create a Macro that hyperlinks data fields to corresponding folders on a local directory in LibryOffice Base?

> **Example:** A client named "Jimmy" is entered in a database. His invoice documents are located in the path "/directory/path/to/jimmy".
>   The DB admin needs the ability to click on Jimmy's ID data field and
>   the corresponding folder.

This macro; however, needs to update an entire database and there are hundreds of client records with a directory structure that's based on the DB data.

> **Example:** Client "A" documents are in "/person/something/a" Client "B" is in "/person/something/b"

If anyone is skilled and willing too assist in writing a VB Macro accomplishing it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet or just asking somebody to write your code?

Comment: I've tried to write it myself with no results. I simply am not fluent enough; however, I did researching other's code and attempted to modify it for my situation. Sorry I'm a noob scripting in BASIC.